# C# Web projects - Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly

Tags: c#, nuget

I am experiencing an unusual issue when I reference a specific internal-only NuGet package from a project in my solution. My solution contains many projects, and a subset of them are web projects. All of the projects in my solution reference a Common project, and when I add the reference to the NuGet package (internal to my company) from the Common project, all of the web projects provide the following assembly conflict warning:

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.

Per the documentation linked in the warning above, since binding redirects do not get automatically generated for web projects, my web projects each use a web.config file to explicitly list the assembly binding redirects. I built each project with build output set to Diagnostic so that I could understand which assemblies are experiencing conflicts, and for each of the web projects, there are about 57 conflicts, including system assemblies, such as:

- System
- System.Net
- System.Core
- System.Xml.Linq
- mscorlib
- System.IO
- System.Net.Http
- System.Collections
- System.Reflection
- System.Runtime

I am not sure what could be causing this issue. I checked with the publisher of the NuGet package and their .NET framework matches that of my solution. None of my other projects besides the web ones seem to be affected. I tried using tools such as dotPeek and fuslogvw to figure out what/where the assemblies are and nothing stood out as a culprit. I started reading into the GAC but did not understand why this would affect my web projects but not my non-web projects.

Any ideas or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to NuGet hell. When you include a package that specifies a dependency on .NET Core or .NET Standard in a traditional .NET Framework app (for a Framework that does not implement .NET Standard), this happens. The best solution is to ask the authors of your internal package to make it do multi-targeting. As far as I can tell, there is no good solution to System.Net.Http (an MSFT guy on GitHub recommends a binding redirect back to the 4.0.0.0 GAC-ed version). Get ready for a frustrating time.

Comment: To your point, we target .NET 4.6.2 and I believe the package targets .NET 4.5. In some of the warning details (when I set build output to Diagnostic) I see that the version of the package that was chosen is depended on by 4.6.2 assemblies whereas the version of the package that was not chosen is depended on by 4.5 assemblies. So, what is the solution?

Comment: Look to see if someone has a dependence on .NET Standard.  That will do it.  Otherwise, look through each package and see if one of them is pulling in something unexpected.  If I had a good solution for you, I'd be much happier.  I had our 39 project solution all cleanly compiling and running 2 weeks ago, then someone added a new feature, pulling in a new package and things went back into the toilet.  We eventually decided to code what the package was providing ourselves as a work-around.  I believe that 4.7.2 and .NET Standard fixes this, be we aren't there yet.

Comment: I do see the following in the .csproj of one of the projects in the NuGet package: `<Reference Include="System.Buffers"><HintPath>$(PkgSystem_Buffers)\lib\netstandard1.1\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath></Reference>`. Do you think that could be the issue?